# How to change font color of all children of a ViewGroup, and differently per ViewGroup instance?

Tags: android

I have a layout for a row to be used in a `ListView`. The layout contains about eight `TextViews`.

If a row represents data of type "A",  I want it to have a red background with light grey font color for all `TextViews`.  If the data is of type "B", I want the background color to be green and the font color to be black.

Right now, I have a custom `ListAdapter` and in the `getView()` method I'm programmatically changing the font color for each `TextView`, but that is very tedious.

I considered defining styles for "A" and "B", but there doesn't seem to be a way to apply a style programmatically (i.e. it can only be done statically in the XML layout).

I also considered having different layouts for "A" and "B", but I don't want to have duplicate code in two XML files.

Any ideas on a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to make the change currently?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/03/15/android-%E2%80%93-applying-alternate-row-color-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/) post show how to have alternate row colors.

Basically you implement `getview` such that you modify some UI components based on your conditions.

You can modify the code from the post for your use.

Comment: That's basically what I said in my question, that I've implemented a custom ListAdapter and overridden the getView() method.  My primary problem isn't the background color... the real problem is changing the font color of eight TextViews.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a decent way of doing this.  Luckily, I am using the [Butter Knife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) library and could use the View Groups feature:

> You can group multiple views into a List or array.

```
@Bind({ R.id.first_name, R.id.middle_name, R.id.last_name }) List<TextView> nameViews;
```

> Action and Setter interfaces allow specifying simple behavior.

```
static final ButterKnife.Setter<TextView, Integer> SET_COLOR = new ButterKnife.Setter<TextView, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void set(TextView view, Integer value, int index) {
            view.setTextColor(value);
        }
    };
```

> The apply method allows you to act on all the views in a list at once.

```
ButterKnife.apply(nameViews, SET_COLOR, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.primary_text_light));
```